# How do I make rsync skip files that failed to transfer?

Tags: rsync

My destination has FAT32 file system, but the directory to sync has files larger than 4G, which result in `File too large (27)` error. How can I tell rsync to continue to the next file when it encounters such situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid the file too large error, you can use the `--max-size=SIZE` option found on the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)  which will tell rsync to ignore files above a certain size.

So in your case the command would be similar to:
`rsync --max-size=3999m /source/files /dest/files`